# including several classes into one file

Tags: php, class, include

I'm trying to include all the classes in my core folder into one file. But, in the initial Core class where I assign the class objects to variables, I  keep getting the error "Fatal Error: Class Not Found"

```
    function inc_files($dir, $ext = false, $publics = array()) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    global $INC_FILE, $INC_DIR; // I don't like using globals, no in the slightest, but sometimes you do need them.
    $INC_DIR = $dir;
    extract($publics, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'inc_');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $INC_FILE = $file;
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file[strlen($file)-1] !== '~' && is_file($dir.'/'.$file))
            if($ext === false || strtolower(substr($file, -(strlen($ext)))) == strtolower($ext))
                include $dir.'/'.$file;
    }
    unset($GLOBALS['INC_DIR']); unset($GLOBALS['INC_FILE']);
}}
```

This is the function I'm using to do this.

Answer (score 1):

use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)   this is made for such help :)

from manual:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```